# MFC dialog window on top of tablet mode view windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dialog, tablet, mode

We are creating a dialog window to display information, this dialog is invoked by application which is running in background on local (Host) machine when it receives instructions from remote machine. This is working fine in Windows 10 OS when running in desktop mode. But we are NOT seeing the dialog when the Windows 10 OS is switched to tablet mode, rather it is in background.

So far we have tried the following,

1. building the application with "UIAccess=true"
2. SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE,
              GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) | WS_MINIMIZEBOX);

   SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE,
              GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);

   SetWindowPos(m_hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0,0,0,  SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE );

Any suggestions.